# Re-deploying war file into tomcat server using jenkins is failing

Tags: tomcat, grails, jenkins

War file deployment into the tomcat server getting success first time(if war file not found in the webapps folder). Again building the war file and deploying the second time it's failing and getting the following error.

```
|Compiling 1 GSP file for package [jasper]
..
|Building WAR file
.............................................................................................
|Done creating WAR target\ROOT.war
Deploying G:\practice\jenkins\jobs\Grails-Jenkins\workspace\ccsystem\target\ROOT.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
  [G:\practice\jenkins\jobs\Grails-Jenkins\workspace\ccsystem\target\ROOT.war] is not deployed. Doing a fresh deployment.
  Deploying [G:\practice\jenkins\jobs\Grails-Jenkins\workspace\ccsystem\target\ROOT.war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [G:\practice\jenkins\jobs\Grails-Jenkins\workspace\ccsystem\target\ROOT.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:185)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3192)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3175)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.pipe(TomcatManager.java:647)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:291)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:102)
    ... 17 more
java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3192)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3175)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.pipe(TomcatManager.java:647)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:291)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:185)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Sending e-mails to: krishna.vardhireddy@gmail.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: try removing the file before placing it there 2nd time.. see if that clears issue

Comment: We don't want to do manually for every deployment. If that the case no use of using jenkins.

Comment: One good habit to get to, is to always clean tomcat cache directory.  /work/Catalina/

Comment: How jenkins will do cache clearing

Comment: I think you should research your errors which started from java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021899/ant-ioexception-error-writing-request-body-to-server-on-deployment-to-tomcat.. Looks like a tomcat configuration - none jenkins related

Answer (score 0):

Use [POST BUILD](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task) plugin (or SSH plugin with `Exec command`). Usually we put there script similar to:

```
sleep 7
rm -rf /home/tomcat_projectName/webapps/api.projectName.com
rm -rf /home/tomcat_projectName/webapps/api.projectName.com.war
cp /home/jenkins/jenkins-data/api.projectName.com.war /home/tomcat_projectName/webapps/api.projectName.com.war
rm -rf /home/jenkins/jenkins-data/api.projectName.com.war
/home/tomcat_projectName/bin/startup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cargo:redeploy` instead of `cargo:deploy` should resolve the issue.